# Delete documents in all collections using indexeradmin rdocs

Tags: fast-esp

Is it possible to use?

```
indexeradmin rdocs list-of-ids.txt
```

to delete all documents across all collections.

I ran the command but found it hadn't deleted the documents, from the docs it says to specify the collection name, I can delete the documents per collection but just wondered if it was possible to have a list of mixed internal_ids from different collections and have indexeradmin delete them all. For example a file containing:

- 0034953453453453_collection1
- 4345345345345334_collection2

would delete the documents in collection1 and 2.

Comment: You need to specify collection and you need to make sure that you do it for all nodes, if you are running FastESP on multiple nodes.

We typically use "indexeradmin --column=1 --row=1 rdocs list-of-ids.txt collection-name unique-identifier" for each column/row of our cluster.

Comment: You can easily get a list of all documents in a collection like this: "indexerinfo -a reportcontents collection-name"

Answer (score 0):

For each collection do this:

```
indexerinfo -a reportcontents collection-name > /tmp/list-of-ids.txt
indexeradmin --column=1 --row=1 rdocs /tmp/list-of-ids.txt collection-name session-id
```

Execute the second line for all columns/rows of the cluster. And you can choose any random integer for the session-id.